# How to UPDATE JSON column array field MySql

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I want to add partners if it partners is not there in my Json column how can i do this ?

```
"partners": [
    {
        "partnerId": 515,
        "partnerName": "Hewlett Packard Enterprise"
    }
]
```

And If partner is empty like this "partners": [] want to update like this

```
{"partners": [
    {
      "partnerId": 515,
      "partnerName": "Hewlett Packard Enterprise"
    }
]}
```

Comment: What if there is already one value in the array, that is some other partner than Hewlett Packard: do you want to add HP to the array or not?

Comment: No I Want to add only if the partners is not there in the Json string or if it is there but Empty like this "partners": []

Comment: Add your table structure in the question

Answer (score 0):

In this condition, you need to send this data from jquery to php in a form of json.
So firstly you need to create a jquery function.

```
function DataTransfer()
{
            var partnerids= [];

            $.each(partnerid), function(){

                partnerids.push(partnerId);

            });
           
           var partnerids_array= JSON.stringify(partnerids);

           $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?action=yourpage',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{partnerids : partnerids_array},
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#content").html(result);
                      }

            });  
}
```

Add partner name too, and post the data to your php file, and use :

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['partnerids ']));
```

and get the data in array.
I hope this will work for you.
Modify the code as per your need.

Comment: Since when do we know the question is relative to PHP/JS ?

Comment: But i want to do using mysql script its a one time task for me I am not using PHP for the Backend

Comment: so what are you using as a backhand? you can now link a work between json and mysql.